# How to get a plot shape function as user input?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I get a plotshape function as user input so that one can manually turn on / off visual effects from the chart?

Answer (score 3):

Example below

```
show = input.bool(false, title = "Show?")
plotshape(show ? close : na, title = "Close", style = shape.labelup, text = "Close", size = size.normal, location = location.belowbar)
```